# Why does a VBA function does not work with PHP 7?

Tags: php, vba, ms-word, dcom, office-automation

I just upgraded my web application to PHP 5.XXX to PHP 7.4.28.

I solved most of the issues so far, but I've been stuck on a VBA (DCOM) function that apparently is not recognized anymore:

`$myTable->Range->InsertBreak(8);`

Where "8" means wdColumnBreak.

Could you please let me know if there is any alternative syntax to make this column break work correctly?

Any suggestions is really appreciated,
Thank you very much

Comment: so what's error?

Comment: Hi, thanks for your reply.

The error is the following: "Fatal error: Uncaught com_exception: Source: Unknown Description: Unknown"
If I comment this line, the Word is generated correctly (but without the column break the formatting is messed up).

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After struggling for a while, I could find the following solution:

```
$myNumber= new VARIANT(8, VT_I4);
$MyTable->Range->InsertBreak($myNumber);
```

Basically the parameter of the InsertBreak function must be treated as a variant, not as a numeric.
With this syntax, it works just fine.

I really wanted to share this solution because I don't like the approach "*this technology is not recommended anymore, just go for the latest one*"...
It's not always so simple to migrate to new technologies (without even having any guarantee about their reliability).

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

The [Considerations for server-side Automation of Office](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/topic/considerations-for-server-side-automation-of-office-48bcfe93-8a89-47f1-0bce-017433ad79e2) article states the following:

> Microsoft does not currently recommend, and does not support, Automation of Microsoft Office applications from any unattended, non-interactive client application or component (including ASP, ASP.NET, DCOM, and NT Services), because Office may exhibit unstable behavior and/or deadlock when Office is run in this environment.

> If you are building a solution that runs in a server-side context, you should try to use components that have been made safe for unattended execution. Or, you should try to find alternatives that allow at least part of the code to run client-side. If you use an Office application from a server-side solution, the application will lack many of the necessary capabilities to run successfully. Additionally, you will be taking risks with the stability of your overall solution.

I'd suggest choosing components designed for the server-side execution instead. Also you may take a look at the [Open XML SDK](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/open-xml/open-xml-sdk) if you deal with open XML documents only.

Comment: Hi Eugene, thanks for your reply.
I understand that this is not the recommended solution by Microsoft, unfortunately my application is totally based on Word documents generated with DCOM via PHP.
I cannot effort to face such a big change right now, all I need is just a quick workaround to make the column break work correctly, it doesn't need to be a perfect or elegant solution...
Thank you very much